# Actionscript 3 authoring tools

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I like the Eclipse SDK for other languages like python/java etc for writing code. But the Flash CS4 environment is not as intuitive (specially the editor). Is there any alternative for writing actionscript?

Comment: There is Flash Builder : http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/ But its for writing Flex based ActionScript.

Flash Develop: is also an alternative ENV which can do Flex or Flash apps but it isn't an Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: so in Flash builder, I can develop as3 and use it in Flash CS4?

Comment: @eSniff You can use Flash Builder to write pure AS3 with no Flex involved.

Comment: @Allan Good to know thank you, I had only used it for MXML applications.

Comment: @eSniff No worries, I thought it was Flex only for quite a while too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FlashDevelop is awesome for coding in ActionScript. Check it out at: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page I find that the code completion in this editor makes development a lot easier than inside Flash.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try the plugin [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/) for Eclipse. It is more powerful than FlashDevelop but not free. [IntelliJ ultimate edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is another alternative. I have heard it is good but have not tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is awful for flash development.

As a Flash developer there is an accepted workflow of which I use.

Flash to do all your graphics and Flex to do the coding. The way it works, is you simply save the files in the right place, and when you run flash - your code is compiled along with the stage graphics you've made.

There are the alternatives like flashDevelop and FDT (both of which are very good).

I like Flash and Flex development because with cs5 and Flash Buillder (Which is the name of the newest flex builder IDE) they integrate and therefore if you can tell FlashBuilder to start a Flash development application, the two IDE's work in tandem.

Here is a link from gotoandlearn.com of which explains how this works http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=60

Here is a nice diagram of how they interconnect http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=A2D85

---

*what are the differences between flash cs5 and cs4? Is there a tutorial/example to cs4/cs5/builder working together? – **iceman***

---

The differences excite different people dependant upon what you like to do.

Drawing upgrades mostly. Backend stuff we don't see. - The interface is still the same - unfortunately.

For developers who use the actionscript window, there is now autosuggest and better syntax highlighting.

The greatest improvement is only visible if you use Flash Builder. It allows you to debug and inspect elements inside flash whilst using flash builder.

With that in mind I was using Flex Builder <> Flash cs4 workflow for a long time. And although you think it may get tiresome. Its so much easier to work in both than just one.

I code in Flex builder - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to flash and hit run! Once I'm done - flick back to flex builder and continue working.

Comment: what are the differences between flash cs5 and cs4? Is there a tutorial/example to cs4/cs5/builder working together?

Answer (score 0):

Flash builder is best for flash based coding also called as flex.
flash builder is eclipse based IDE to code RIA in flash.