# Differences in actionscript 3 authoring tools

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What are the various feature differences between different as3 authoring tools like: FlashDevelop,FDT,Flash builder? ref [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418550/actionscript-3-authoring-tools)

Comment: [Am I reading this right](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/features/)?  You don't get a debugger with FDT unless you pay for the most expensive version?  What kind of "Professional" IDE doesn't have a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FDT and Flash Builder are very similar, both are based on eclipse and both share features such as refactoring, profiling and debugging. However FDT (enterprise) has more features. Useful features are:

- Real time syntax error checking
- Find all references to a particular function in a project
- In built support for ANT
- Quick assist
- Template shortcuts (couldn't seem to find this in flash builder but might be a way)
- Alpha Haxe support

FDT Enterprise is pretty expensive though. Alternatively, there is the free FlashDevelop, built on .NET - so it is pretty much for Windows only.

Its features are more bare bone but still has some things one would expect like code assist and does include support for Haxe which FlashBuilder does not.

There is also IntelliJ Ultimate edition which has support for AS3 but have not tried it. The flash guru Joa Ebert swtiched to IntelliJ from FDT for enterprise development http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2010/03/06/compiling-actionscript-in-the-enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

you can read it here

http://flash.developerartofwar.com/2008/04/24/flexbuilder-3-vs-fdt-3/

but if you're looking for advice:

use FlashBuilder, because its officially supported by Adobe, based on eclipse with wide experts community and plugins repository, its have **best** profiler and debuger, IMHO of course.

Regards
Eugene